# Can not connect to LDAPS server from PHP 5.5.4 on Windows 7 64bit, Apache 2.4

Tags: php, windows, apache, ssl, ldap

I can not connect to LDAPS server (3rd party) from PHP (*PHP 5.5.4, Apache 2.4, Windows 7 64bit*). When I'm trying `ldap_bind()` function with userdn and password, I receive - `Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server.`

I have self-signed certificate from the LDAPS server, but I don't know where to put the PEM file (Base64) or something like conf.file (I have read many answers for this, but nothing works for me - e.g. `c:\openldap\sysconf\ldap.conf`, `TLS_REQCERT` never etc.).

Development folder is `D:\WebDev` where inside is `\www` folder with projects and `\binaries` folder with `\Apache` folder and `\PHP` folder. PHP is an module for Apache and Apache is started by `httpd.exe --standalone --console`.

`Openssl s_client -connect xxxx -CAfile xxxx` to LDAPS server works good, return code is `0`. Without `-CAfile` I fet `code 19 (self-signed certificate in certificate chain)`.

LDAP without SSL works fine for me, I've tried some free online LDAP test server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Notice: there is no Openldap installation on the machine.

Solution is to set Windows system variable LDAPCONF, value is e.g. `c:\users\user\.ldaprc` and in the file `.ldaprc` set the path to certificate e.g. `TLS_CACERT c:\users\user\.ssh\ldap-ca.pem` or `TLS_REQCERT never`, both is working.

Then connection script from console or via Apache from browser is running OK.

The default search path for conf is c:\users\user\, but for browser app running via Apache must be set the system variable LDAPCONF.

I hope this help !